# The "login or register" link is invisible in Internet Explorer

Tags: support, design

The "Please login or register to vote for this post" text doesn't display correctly when viewed in Internet Explorer 9 on Windows 7 Professional SP1 64-bit:

[image: Ask Ubuntu in Internet Explorer 9]

Comment: You should be asking this on SO meta.  That's where issues with the stack network have in my experience been directed

Comment: @aking1012 I believe the bug tag gets picked up across all sites now

Comment: @aking1012 Even if it's related to AU's styles?

Comment: @aking1012 No. Posting on meta.au is the correct thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce this in regular IE9; however, this indeed happens when you switch to compatibility mode (because it doesn't support `color: inherit`), so I'm fairly certain that your browser is in that mode. Compat mode essentially turns the browser into IE7, which we don't support anymore. If you turn of compatibility mode, you should be able to see the link.